Custom JSF form login issue to start session and land on home
I am using myfaces 2 and trying to shift from form based authentication with j_security to custom login form. I have B2B login where call goes to third party system to validate username and password and based on response redirection happens.
But, redirection is what not working even after a successful B2B authentication. even more strange, we could see redirected url in browser but view is not renderring.
I am new to jsf and struggling with this issue since long. any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code
Web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <description>abc web project</description>
    <!-- Project-Stage wird mit Maven gesetzt -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>${webxml.stage}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Configure tomahawk taglib -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tld/std.taglib.xml; 
            /WEB-INF/tld/pqr.taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/tld/pqrabc.taglib.xml;</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Comma separated list of URIs of (additional) faces config
            files. (e.g. /WEB-INF/my-config.xml) See JSF 1.0 PRD2,
            10.3.2 Attention: You do not need to put
            /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml in here.</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces/config.xml,
    /WEB-INF/faces/bean.xml,
    /WEB-INF/faces/navigation.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: "client" or "server" (= default) See
            JSF Specification 2.5.3</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Define partial state saving as true/false.</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>ilp.faces.VIEW_EXPIRED_REDIRECT_URL</param-name>
        <param-value>/pages/home.jsf</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SUPPORT_JSP_AND_FACES_EL</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (=
            default). Defines the amount (default = 20) of the latest
            views are stored in session.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (=
            default). If true (default) the state will be serialized to
            a byte stream before it is written to the session. If false
            the state will not be serialized to a byte stream.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Only applicable if state saving method is "server" (=
            default) and if
            org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION is true (=
            default) If true (default) the serialized state will be
            compressed before it is written to the session. If false the
            state will not be compressed.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be
            allowed in the rendered HTML output. If javascript is
            allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code that
            submits the corresponding form. If javascript is not
            allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters will be
            added as url parameters. Default: "true"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is
            "human readable". i.e. additional line separators and
            whitespace will be written, that do not influence the HTML
            code. Default: "true"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able
            to restore the former vertical scroll on every request.
            Convenient feature if you have pages with long lists and you
            do not want the browser page to always jump to the top if
            you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same
            page. Default: "false"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Used for encrypting view state. Only relevant for client
            side state saving. See MyFaces wiki/web site documentation
            for instructions on how to configure an application for
            diffenent encryption strengths.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SECRET</param-name>
        <param-value>NzY1NDMyMTA=</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Validate managed beans, navigation rules and ensure that
            forms are not nested.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE</param-name>
        <param-value>${webxml.validateConfig}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Treat readonly same as if disabled attribute was set for
            select elements.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.READONLY_AS_DISABLED_FOR_SELECTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Virtual path in the URL which triggers loading of resources
            for the MyFaces extended components in the ExtensionFilter.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_VIRTUAL_PATH</param-name>
        <param-value>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Myfaces default context params -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DISABLE_TOMAHAWK_FACES_CONTEXT_WRAPPER</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Check if the extensions-filter has been properly configured.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_CLEAR_JAVASCRIPT_FOR_BUTTON</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_HIDDEN_FIELDS_FOR_LINK_PARAMS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_FORM_SUBMIT_LINK_IE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_VIEWSTATE_ID</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_XHTML_LINKS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_FORM_SUBMIT_SCRIPT_INLINE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VIEWSTATE_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS</param-name>
        <param-value>auto</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS_PRESERVE_STATE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE_XML</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.WRAP_SCRIPT_CONTENT_WITH_XML_COMMENT_TAG</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INITIALIZER</param-name>
        <param-value>example.business.ilp.faces.core.application.CustomFaceletsInitializer</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>example.business.pqr.abcclient.security.AutoLoginFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>permittedPages</param-name>
            <param-value>/, /login.jsf, /index.jsp, /error401.jsf, /error403.jsf, /error405.jsf, /error408.jsf, /error500.jsf</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>permittedGets</param-name>
            <param-value>/error401.jsf, /error403.jsf, /error405.jsf, /error408.jsf, /error500.jsf, /pages/home.jsf, /pages/selectArbeitsbereich.jsf, /pages/selectArbeitsbereichPA.jsf, /pages/continueSession.jsf, /login.jsf, /pages/webEntry.jsf, /js/jsUtils.js, /css/basic.css, /css/resolution/basic240x320.css</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <!-- Extensions Filter -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Extensions Filter -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Index Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Index Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>example.business.pqr.abcclient.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Index Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Index Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- MIME Mapping für MC55 Support -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <!-- Session-Timeout wird jetzt Websphere konfiguriert <session-config><session-timeout>480</session-timeout></session-config> Welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/error401.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error403.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/error405.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>408</error-code>
        <location>/error408.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error500.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Forbidden</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Methods</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restricted</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Authorized user roles</description>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error401.jsf</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>Authenticated user for servlet</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>

Custom filter
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
 
        final HttpServletRequest hreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final HttpServletResponse hres = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        final String contextPath = hreq.getContextPath();
        final String requestUri = hreq.getRequestURI();
        String requestedPage = getRequestedResource(contextPath, requestUri);
 
        if (restrictedPageRequest(hreq, requestedPage)) {
            handleRestrictedPageRequest(hreq, hres, chain);
        } else if (forbiddenMethod(hreq, requestedPage)) {
            handleForbiddenMethodRequest(hreq, hres);
        } else if (forbiddenResourceRequest(requestedPage)) {
            handleForbiddenResourceRequest(hreq, hres);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

login.xhtml
<h:form id="form" class="formTable">
   <t:div styleClass="mainPaneBig" id="theContent">
      <t:panelGrid styleClass="subpane" columns="2" columnClasses="column20 fontForLabelBig, column80 fontForDataBig" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
         <t:outputLabel id="usernameLabel" for="username"
            value="#{msg['abc.login.txt.usernameLabel']}"
            styleClass="longLabel fontForLabel" />
         <h:inputText id="username" required="true" value="#{loginBean.username}"     styleClass="loginInput fontForData" maxlength="256" tabindex="1" onfocus="goInInputText('username')"
            onblur="goOutInputText('username')"
            onkeypress="keyIsPressedForOrder('loginButton')" />
         <t:outputLabel id="passwordLabel" for="password"
            value="#{msg['abc.login.txt.passwordLabel']}"
            styleClass="longLabel fontForLabel" />
         <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}"
            required="true" tabindex="2" styleClass="loginInput fontForData"
            onfocus="goInInputText('password')"
            onkeypress="keyIsPressedForOrder('loginButton')"
            onblur="goOutInputText('password')" />
      </t:panelGrid>
   </t:div>
   <t:div id="messagePane" styleClass="messagesPane">
      <t:messages styleClass="infoMessages fontForLabel fontForMessage shiftMarginTop" />
      <t:outputText id="messages"styleClass="infoMessages fontForLabel fontForMessage shiftMarginTop" />
   </t:div>
   <t:div styleClass="navigationPane" id="navi">
      <t:panelGrid cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" columns="3"
         columnClasses="columnForNavigation, columnForNavigation, columnForNavigation"
         styleClass="bottomPane">
         <t:commandButton id="resetButton"
            value="#{msg['abc.login.button.reset']}"
            onfocus="goInCommandButton('resetButton')"
            onblur="goOutCommandButton('resetButton')"
            styleClass="navigateButton fontForLabelBig"
            onclick="setCursorToUsername()" />
         <t:commandButton id="emptyButton" value="" disabled="true"
            styleClass="navigateButton" />
         <h:commandButton id="loginButton"
            value="#{msg['abc.login.button.login']}"
            action="#{loginBean.login}" tabindex="3"
            styleClass="navigateButton fontForLabelBig"
            onclick="return validateInputs();"
            onfocus="goInCommandButton('loginButton')"
            onblur="goOutCommandButton('loginButton')" />
      </t:panelGrid>
   </t:div>
</h:form>

loginBean.java
public bool function login() {  
    final User user = new User(username, password);
    boolean flag = false;
    final HttpServletRequest request = FacesUtils.getServletRequest();
    request.getSession().getAttribute("password");
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    //outcome = "webEntry";
    CustomHttpServletRequest custom = new CustomHttpServletRequest(request);
    custom.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic ************");
    if (!service.validateUser(custom, user)) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("User not found with username: " + username));
        flag = false;
    } else {
        flag = login(user.getUsername());
    }
    return flag;
}



I want to user to land on a home page (web entry) after successful B2B authentication and set the login session.
Unfortunately, It's not happening after changing from j_security_check to normal custom login with loginBean. don't know where I am lagging.
